Old comedic movie possible late 70's Japanese boy and his bodyguard lead role
I'm looking for a movie that I saw when I was a child and that I have never heard of again or met anyone who saw it. It was an old comedic movie, possibly from the late 70's.
It was about Japanese boy and his bodyguard. I thought the body guard was Bud Spencer in dubious make up to make him look more Asian, but cannot trace a film like this he was in. He was assigned to protect the child.
The part that sticks in the mind is that gems were hidden in cherries but nobody knew this other than possibly the boy's father. Leading up to the end of the film, the boy and the minder (who did not know about the gems being in the cherries) had eaten all the cherries and gems thinking the gems were the stones in the cherries. In the final scene to retrieve the gems they had to let nature take their course sat on large ceramic vases (it was possibly in a palace or the boy's rich father's home). The body guard breaks wind and blows up the vase.
I know crazy, but that film has bugged me for years as to what it was and no doubt it possibly would not be funny now, but who knows.

There was indeed a Bud Spencer movie where he was an Italian police officer protecting a young Japanese boy that the Mafia were after. The movie is called Piedone a Hong Kong AKA Flatfoot in Hong Kong AKA Flatfoot Goes East.

Commissary Rizzo in Napoli gets a message from a policeman from South Africa who wants to meet him. Immediatlz before this meeting the south African policeman is killed. Dying he shows Rizzo a picture of his little son Bodo. Riyyo travels to Johannesburg to find out what the policeman was working on and to find Bodo.

And here's a trailer. The kid appears at the 1:40 mark.



On a related note, RIP Bud Spencer :(

Thank you for looking, I found a link on YouTube to the film above and skipped along it to check it out, but its not the one. The preserved cherries with gems they ate is not in this movie and at one point he was dressed as a sort of samurai. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJrOcAw00Ao
